# Does new IDEA update all SVN modules or only highlighted one?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

In new IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4 CE, I noticed a new screen when I try to update SVN project.

Now, since my project (Android) consists of 3 modules, I am not sure if all of them are being updated or only the selected one. Look at the image.

[image]

What is even more confusing is that I am **unable to select all of my projects**, but I have to update one by one. This process is very slow and frustrating since I have to wait for the current update to finish before I start a new update.

Answer (score 1):

I've been just using a workaround. I highlight all of the top-level directories in the project viewer, then right-click->subversion->"update directories" to update them all at once. Seems to work pretty smoothly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @sandalone never knew about Ctrl+T. Good to know.